# Eigenfunction of $(a(x) f^{II})^{II}= - \lambda^2f$

Tags: calculus, analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need the eigenfunctions $f$ and eigenvalues $\lambda$  of  $(a(x) f^{II}(x))^{II}= - \lambda^2f$ for a given $a(x)$. 
For $a(x)$ constant the solution is a combination of sin, cos, sinh and cosh.
For $a(x)$ not constant one gets $af^{IV}+2a^{I}f^{III}+a^{II}f^{II}+\lambda^2f=0$

How could i find a way to find $\lambda$ and $f(x)$ if $a(x)$ is not constant?

Comment: Notation: What do you mean by $f^{IV},f^{III},f^{II},a^{I}$ ?

Comment: @Américo: Derivatives, it seems.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks! Maybe. But I am used to see $f^{(4)},\dots$ instead.

Comment: @Américo: I meant derivatives. I hope that helps, is there anything else unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $g(x) = a(x) f''(x)$.  We then have $\begin{pmatrix} f''(x) \\ g''(x) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1/a(x) \\ -\lambda^2 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} f(x) \\ g(x) \end{pmatrix}$.

We can try to integrate this, it's not easy (very difficult for arbitrary $a$).  Like the constant $a$ case, one has solutions for pretty much any value of $\lambda$.

(It is in fact a bit easier to expand this to a 4x4 first-order matrix ODE by defining auxiliary variables for $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$, but I'll leave that to you.)